# Scala currying example

Tags: scala, currying

I am new to scala and was going through the coursera course for scala functional development. Below the code snippet explains about currying

```
import math.abs

object exercise{
    val tolerance = 0.0001

    def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double) = abs((x -y)/x)/x < tolerance

    def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double) = {
      def iterate(guess: Double):Double = {
        val next = f(guess)
          if ( isCloseEnough(guess, next)) next
          else iterate(next)
        }
      iterate(firstGuess)
    }

    def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double) = ( x + f(x))/2

    def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint( averageDamp(y => x/y))(1)
}
```

I cant understand the following part of the code

> `fixedPoint( averageDamp(y => x/y))(1)`

I know that averageDamp function takes 2 arguments (one is function and the other is value for x) but when it is called from fixedPoint, we don't pass the value of x. So I assumed that it is creating a partial function which is sent back to sqrt where the value of x is passed from sqrt(x: Double) agrument. So I made the following function which fails to compile

> `def noIdea(x: Double) = averageDamp( y => x/y)`

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply an underscore in order to trigger an [eta expansion](http://blog.jaceklaskowski.pl/2013/11/23/how-much-one-ought-to-know-eta-expansion.html) on the unapplied method. Methods have no value so they must be converted into a function object in order to be assigned to a variable. When Scala knows that the unapplied method should be interpreted as a function object, the eta expansion is triggered automatically. In other cases you need to trigger the expansion manually with an underscore.

Not sure what your Scala version is, but 2.11.7 makes this pretty clear. Here is a simple example with a scaling function:

```
scala> def my_scaler(sc: Double)(x: Double): Double = sc*x

my_scaler: (sc: Double)(x: Double)Double

scala> def my_doubler = my_scaler(2d) // no eta exp
<console>:13: error: missing argument list for method my_scaler
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `my_scaler _` or `my_scaler(_)(_)` instead of `my_scaler`.
       def my_doubler = my_scaler(2d)
                                 ^

scala> def my_doubler = my_scaler(2d) _ // manual eta exp
my_doubler: Double => Double

scala> my_doubler(10d)
res1: Double = 20.0

scala> def my_tripler: Double => Double  = my_scaler(3d) // auto eta exp
my_tripler: Double => Double

scala> my_tripler(10d)
res2: Double = 30.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works with the underscore but if you notice i did not put the underscore for 
> def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint( averageDamp(y => x/y))(1) 
It still works, what kind of magic is this???

Comment: Because in that case it is expecting a function, the same would be the case if you gave `noIdea` a type of `Double => Double`. When Scala knows the value is supposed to be a function (`A => B`), it automatically  triggers what is known as an eta expansion, read more [here](http://blog.jaceklaskowski.pl/2013/11/23/how-much-one-ought-to-know-eta-expansion.html). Providing an underscore triggers this automatically.

Comment: now i understand the magic behind this. Thanks for the link and your example :)

Answer (score 4):

Creating a curried function like that only works if you are passing it as an argument to another function or in some other case where a function is expected. Since `fixedPoint` receives a function you can simply write:

```
fixedPoint( averageDamp(y => x/y))(1)
```

When you want to create a curried function where one is not expected Scala makes you add a `_` or `(_)(_)` to confirm your intention:

```
def noIdea(x: Double) = averageDamp( y => x/y) _
```

Another way to avoid it in this case would be to specify the return type for `noIdea`:

```
def noIdea(x: Double): Double => Double  = averageDamp( y => x/y)
```

The `_` is simply a way to make sure that you really want to create a function and did not forget to pass an additional argument.